# Split STRING into OR in Access SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'll start by saying I understand very little of SQL which is why I haven't tried doing this myself.
What I'm looking to achieve is as follows. I have a string with several unique IDs and I'm trying to use them to retrieve several rows of a table via a query.

mystring = 26,28,29,30

My goal would be to reach table "PartsList" and retrieve the field "Name" from rows 26, 28, 29 and 30.

How would I go about this?

EDIT: This is what I was using previously to retrieve info for just one row:

```
SELECT PartsList.ID, PartsList.Name, 
FROM PartsList
WHERE (((PartsList.Part_Number)=[Forms]![View_Parts]![Name]));
```

Thanks in advance, Rafael.

Comment: Fix your data model!  You should not be storing numbers as strings.  You should not be storing multiple values in a single column.  You should be declaring foreign key relationships.  Your data model is broken.

Comment: How would I go about doing it then? I'm getting this string from a Form where a user can select multiple choices from a listbox.

Comment: *from rows 26, 28, 29 and 30* which column's values are these numbers? Is it `PartsList.ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`LIKE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931) operator:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM PartsList
WHERE (',' & mystring & ',') LIKE ('*,' & ID & ',*');
```

If `mystring` may contain spaces, remove them with [`REPLACE()`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/replace-function-6acf209b-01b7-4078-b4b8-e0a4ef67d181):

```
SELECT Name 
FROM PartsList
WHERE (',' & REPLACE(mystring, ' ', '') & ',') LIKE ('*,' & ID & ',*');
```